# Android AudioTrack.write() returns after playing the whole buffer

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

AudioTrack.write(). Android documentation says that

> In streaming mode, the write will normally block until all the data has been enqueued for playback, and will return a full transfer count.

However, in my code, write() method seems to wait until the whole buffer is played until the from the loudspeaker. Therefore, for example calling stop() method afterwards or filling more data is not possible.

The audiotrack is initialized by:

```
int mBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT);
AudioTrack mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
        mBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
int duration = 44100*5;
short[] mBuffer = new short[duration];
```

In onCreate:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wavelength; i++) {
        waveform[i] = Math.sin(((double) i)/wavelength * 2 * Math.PI - Math.PI);
}
mAudioTrack.play();
```

On a button click, this is called:

```
private void playSound(double frequency, int duration) {
    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < duration-1; i++) {
        idx = idx + (int) Math.ceil(frequency);
        if (idx > wavelength-1)
            idx = idx % wavelength;
        mBuffer[i] = (short) (waveform[idx] * Short.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ret = mAudioTrack.write(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.length);
    long runtime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    debugText.setText(Long.toString(runtime));
}
```

The timestamp shows that the write() call takes exactly 5 seconds, which is the length of the audio clip, and I wouldn't believe the transfer time would be exactly the same. I want to generate more data to be played (perhaps with another frequency) while the previous data is still being played. I know some developers use multiple threads (and I have no experience in threading, so I don't know how to do it), but the documentation indicates it would be possible also this way...

Comment: What's the value of mBufferSize?

Comment: Debugger says it's 1764. I don't actually know exactly what this buffer size does. I tried to make it bigger, but it crashed.

Comment: 1764 bytes is enough for only 20ms of mono, 16-bit, 44.1kHz audio. Understanding this buffer is key to understanding your problem. No idea about the crash, maybe that's a different problem? (PS I assume the AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT in the getMinBufferSize call is a typo)

Comment: Thank you for answer. You are right. I added the cause of this crash to the original message.

Comment: And by the way, what do you mean by typo? It seems to work.

Comment: You should probably ask about the maximum size of an AudioTrack's stream buffer as a new question. (As for the typo - you're configuring an AudioTrack for 16-bit audio, why try for the estimated minimum buffer size for 8-bit audio?)

Comment: I reverted the edit. I will post another question, if I will not find a solution. You are right about 16 vs 8 bit audio. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A call to `AudioTrack.write(...)` blocks until all of the supplied data has been copied into the AudioTrack's streaming buffer. The AudioTrack buffer's size (`mBufferSize` above) is set to `AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(...)`, and so is obviously small, surely enough for only a fraction of a second of audio.

The 5 seconds of audio data that you want to enqueue will obviously not fit into such a small buffer. So `AudioTrack.write(...)` must repeatedly fill that buffer as it is being drained by playback. Before it can return it must enqueue the last part of your audio data. And before it can do that it must wait at least until everything but the last `mBufferSize` of audio data has been played.

If you increase `mBufferSize` by various amounts you should start to see the `AudioTrack.write` call blocking for less time.